# Find numbers with largest sum (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function that will find which collection of numbers in the array adds up to the largest sum, and puts that number into the new array:

```
var num = ['267453', '345678', '876787'];
var newArray = [];
```

I'm actually at a loss here and not sure how to get started on this problem. 
Can someone help get me off on the right foot?

Comment: Is each string a collection, or is each string a number?

Comment: You will probably have to iterate over the array, split each number string into its digits, add them up. add them tu the array and finally sort the array.

Comment: each string is a number

Comment: Then that means its just the sum of all the items in the array... Your question is unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the strings, split the in to digits sum the digits

```
var arrayLength = num.length;
var sums = []
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
 var digitsAsChar = num[i].split("");
 var tmpSum=0;
 var digitsLength = digitsAsChar.length;
 for(var y=0; y<digitsLength;y++){
   tmpSum = tmpSum+parseInt(digitsAsChar[y]);
 }
 sums.push(tmpSum)
}
```

finaly sort the array:

sums.sort():

Answer (score 3):

```
var num = ['267453', '345678', '876787']; 
var sums =[];

num.forEach(function (el) {
string = el.split('');                 //split into individual characters
    var sum = 0;                               //have a storage ready
    for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {  //iterate through
        sum += parseInt(string[i],10);         //convert from string to int
    }
    sums.push( sum); 

} 

Array.prototype.max = function() {
  return Math.max.apply(null, this);
};


alert("Max value is: "+sums.max());
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you can achieve this rather easily.

```
var num = ['267453', '345678', '876787'];
var max = -Infinity;
var maxi = 0;
num.forEach(function (el, i) {
  var n = el.split('').reduce(function (a, b) {
    return parseInt(a,10) + parseInt(b,10);
  });
  if (n > max) {
      max = n;
      maxi = i;
  }
})
console.log(max); //43
console.log(num[maxi]); //"876787"
```

Regarding performance, this calls `parseInt` a number of times more than strictly necessary, if speed is a problem you may want to consider parsing first and summing separately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fiddle for this :

```
var num = ['267453', '345678', '876787'];
var newArray = [];
var html = '';
for(var n=0; n<num.length; n++) {
    var len = num[n].length;
    count = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
         count += parseInt(num[n].substring(i,i+1));
        //console.log(count);
    }
    var temp1 = parseInt(num[n]); 
    newArray.push(count);
}
newArray = newArray.sort();
newArray = newArray.reverse();
var max = newArray[0];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o6mryk1q/1/